# How to set an variable as a link in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

```
inputBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    myLeads.push(inputEl.value)
    inputEl.value = ""
    let linksFromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem("Leads")
    localStorage.setItem("Leads", JSON.stringify(myLeads))
    render(myLeads)
})

function render(Leads){
    let listItems = ""
    for(i = 0; i < Leads.length; i++){
        listItems += `
            <li>
                <a href='${Leads[i]}' target='_blank'> 
                    ${Leads[i]}
                </a>
            </li>`
    }
    ulEl.innerHTML = listItems
}
```

I have written these two codes but whenever I input a link for example "www.google.com" and then click on the link it does not go to google.com. It shows an error "ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"
Does anybody know how I can fix this? I am really new to Javascript and HTML and would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Likely `${Leads[i]}` is not doing what it should. What is the complete error in the console?

Comment: The link needs to be something like `//www.google.com` or `https://www.google.com`. If you leave out `//`, it's treated as a filename in the same domain as your page.